# When a certain word is found, only set the upmost/nested innertext/innerhtml to ''

Tags: javascript, jquery, userscripts

I am looking for a certain word, for instance "unique" on the current webpage to remove the content of the directly surrounding tag, but not more.

Example

```
<div>    
  <div>test unique is     
  </div>    
</div>    
<p>Hello     
</p>
```

becomes

```
<div>    
  <div>   
  </div>    
</div>    
<p>Hello     
</p>
```

Iow, innerText or innerHTML of the containing tag is set to ''.

So far, I did

```
<script>
var badDivs = $("div:contains('unique')");
badDivs.remove ();
</script>
```

but I want to

1. include all tags, not just div
2. only want the upmost tag to be set to '', not the whole page be blank because somewhere nested there is the word unique.
3. It should work with tags that have or don't have attributes as in the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as though you don't want to remove the tag, only its contents Since the selector `*:contains('unique')` selects every element, including the parents, you'll want to grab the last element selected.. See [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/), [`last`](http://api.jquery.com/last/), and [`empty`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/).

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).find(":contains('unique')").not("script").last().empty();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>test unique is
  </div>
</div>
<p>Hello
</p>
```

In the case of this Stack Snippet, the script in inserted into the `body` element in the `iframe`, so I've specifically excluded those elements.

Comment: This will wipe out the whole page. `<body>` will contain that string

Comment: That works well. What would it look like if I wanted to use more words in an OR fashion, ie remove the content if the document contains `unique` or `special`

Comment: You'd want to do the same line of code for each word. The `last()` depends on there being a single `:contains` selector.

Answer (score 1):

Filter elements that contain the text but don't have any other children.

```js
$(':contains("unique")').filter(function(){
  return !$(this).children().length;
}).empty()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>test unique is
  </div>
</div>
<p>Hello
</p>
```